# Валидация. Поставить курсор в первое обязательное не заполненное поле

Tags: валидация, javascript

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки, помогите, пожалуйста...
итак, есть валидация формы на js, ее код:

```
function validate_OP(){
     //Считаем значения из полей name и email в переменные x и y
     var x=document.forms['jForm']['company'].value;
     var y=document.forms['jForm']['fio'].value;
     var q=document.forms['jForm']['phone'].value;
     var w=document.forms['jForm']['mail'].value;
     //Если поле name пустое выведем сообщение и предотвратим отправку формы
     if (x.length==0){
        alert("Вы не указали свою организацию");
        document.getElementById('company').style.border = "1px solid red";
        //document.getElementById('company').innerHTML = '<br />Вы не указали свою  организацию';
        return false;
     }

  if (y.length==0){
        alert("Представьтесь пожалуйста нам");
        document.getElementById('fio').style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
     }

  if (q.length==0){
        alert("Укажите Ваш контактный номер");
        document.getElementById('phone').style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
     }

     //Если поле email пустое выведем сообщение и предотвратим отправку формы
     if (w.length==0){
        alert ("Нам понадобится и Ваша почта");
        document.getElementById('mail').style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
     }
     //Проверим содержит ли значение введенное в поле email символы @ и .
     at=w.indexOf("@");
     dot=w.indexOf(".");
     //Если поле не содержит эти символы знач email введен не верно
     if (at<1 || dot <1){
        alert ("E-mail введен не коректно, будьте внимательны!");
        document.getElementById('mail').style.border = "1px solid red";
        return false;
     }
  }
```

валидация работает хорошо, теперь вопрос....
как сделать чтоб автоматически курсор ставился в первое обязательное не заполненное поле???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<document.forms['jForm'].length; i++)
{
    if ((document.forms['jForm'][i].id == 'mail' ||
        document.forms['jForm'][i].id == 'fio' ||
        document.forms['jForm'][i].id == 'phone')
        && document.forms['jForm'][i].val == ''
        )//or some other logic for required fields, like special class
    {
        document.forms['jForm'][i].focus();break;

    }
}
```

Comment: ээээмм, а можно расписать? )) для особо одаренного)

Comment: @kiberchainik расписать==объяснить? если "да", то, что именно?